# how to vertically populate data cells in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to vertically populate data cells with array.

This is a simple html table

```
<table>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
 </table>
```

Existing table:

```
Name Value
X 
Y
```

Expected output:

```
Name Value
X     54
Y     48
```

I need to fill the data cells for value. I have calculated values for it and stored in array. How to populate the values using angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ngRepeat to add a new row for each element in your list. See the [docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for examples of how to use this directive.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
<td>{{row.name}}</td>
<td>{{row.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank u. I have only the values in the array. It is not stored as name, value pair.

Comment: Where are the names coming from? You could use the index of the repeater to label them if required.

Answer (score 0):

Use directive for this. Look

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}).directive('indexItemTable', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var data = scope.data;
            angular.element(element).find("td").each(function(index, item){
              console.log(item)
                angular.element(this).parent().append('<td>' + data[index] + '</td>');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController">
    <table index-item-table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the values stored in the array will be dynamic. Need to loop through dynamic array.